# Magento 2 - "The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists." even though the value does not exist in url_rewrite

Tags: url-rewrite

I get "**The value specified in the URL Key field would generate a URL that already exists.**" but I checked the table "**url_rewrite**" and there is no entry with that key.

The URL is "**verbrauchscalculator**". If I call the URL in the browser, then a page opens.

There is also no category where the name is "verbrauchscalculator".

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason why the URL exist. There is a extension with a route which is set to `verbrauchscalculator`.

Answer (score 0):

run this command to check the record in the table `url_rewrite` again for sure:

```
SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite` WHERE `request_path` = 'verbrauchscalculator'
```

Comment: No results. But thx!

Comment: @Black So, try to clear Varnish cache and Redis cache. Might be it help!